# SSDT Stored procedures automatically divided into sub folders

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures, sql-server-data-tools

I have imported a very large data base having about 2000 stored procedures in SSDT to create dacpac. But I was suprised to see all my stored procedures was automatically divided into sub folder, like:

```
1) Procs1
2) Procs2
3) Procs3
```

I don't know the reason. Please help me out in this.

Comment: Are you using SQL Server, and not MySQL? (Two different products, and ssdt is usually used with SQL Server.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you import from a database you are asked how may you want in each folder, I think it defaults to 1000

If you want to have them in one folder you can just move them via solution explorer.

Comment: Along those lines, with that many stored procs, you may want to try to organize them into multiple folders just to make it easier to find them - either by schema, functional area, or some other criteria.  You can always use the SQL Explorer to see them all at once (a feature I frequently forget about).